# Unable to write data in a csv file using dictwriter

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to scrape some `item names`, `estimated time` along with `reviews`, `reviewers` and `rating` connected to each `item name` from a webpage using their api and write them to a csv file. The thing is my below script can parse the data accordingly but I can't write them to a csv file.

However, when I try to write them to a csv file I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\demo000000.py", line 71, in <module>
    w.writerow(reviews)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 151, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'reviews'
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
import csv
import requests

url = "https://eatstreet.com/api/v2/restaurants/{}?yelp_site="

res = requests.get("https://eatstreet.com/api/v2/locales/madison-wi/restaurants")
with open('reviews.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,['name','eta','messg','reviewer','rating'])
    w.writeheader()
    for item in res.json():
        itemid = item['id']
        req = requests.get(url.format(itemid))
        if not 'yelpReviews' in req.json():continue
        reviews = {}
        reviews['name'] = req.json()['name']
        reviews['eta'] = req.json()['waitTime']
        reviews['reviews'] = []
        for texualreviews in req.json()['yelpReviews']:
            reviews_data = {'messg':texualreviews['message'],'reviewer':texualreviews['reviewerName'],'rating':texualreviews['rating']}
            reviews['reviews'].append(reviews_data)
        w.writerow(reviews)
```

Any help to write the scraped data in a csv file will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing.

```
w = csv.DictWriter(f,['name','eta','messg','reviewer','rating'])
```

to

```
w = csv.DictWriter(f,['name','eta', 'reviews','reviewer','rating'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'reviews'
```

Above error indicate that while writing to CSV file there is mismatch in mapping values.
Make change in your code as

```
 w = csv.DictWriter(f,['name', 'eta', 'reviews', 'reviewer', 'rating'])

 ...

 for texualreviews in req.json()['yelpReviews']:
   reviews_data = {'reviews':texualreviews['message'],'reviewer':texualreviews['reviewerName'],'rating':texualreviews['rating']}
   reviews['reviews'].append(reviews_data)
   w.writerow(reviews)
```

Comment: @gboffi appreciate your edit I want to highlight changes in bold which is not possible in code part of the answer.

Comment: Sorry, it is not possible to have bold parts in code using markdown.  _Maybe_  it is possible to do what you want using directly HTML — my advice is "it's not necessary".

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) states that:

> If the dictionary passed to the `writerow()` method contains a key not
>   found in *fieldnames*, the optional *extrasaction* parameter indicates
>   what action to take. If it is set to `'raise'`, the default value, a
>   `ValueError` is raised.

Your call to `writerow()` passes the dictionary `reviews` as the argument, whose keys are `name`, `eta`, and `reviews`. Therefore, the line right below the `with` statement should be:

```py
w = csv.DictWriter(f, ['name', 'eta', 'reviews'])
```

Other fields are not necessary; if added they will just be filled in as empty.